# Is there anything to limit LED output dimming 50% while the wall dimmer controls 50% to 0%?

Tags: led, led-driver, power-engineering, dimming, lighting

We got a project for a client but our lights are too bright for the space, we still want to sell the the lights because we have extra inventory and need a way to dim the LED output to 25W instead of 50W while the wall switch still controls dimming as if it was normal.

Someone suggested something like this: https://ctmlyng.no/wp-content/uploads/Datasheet_MDimLed_Micro_1403888_LR.pdf

But having a hard time finding the real name or even know if that would work the same way as mentioned above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you modify the Fixtures? You could also add a buck transformer to drop the voltage. Just a guess as there not enough information.

Comment: Need light datasheet pls

Comment: I would call this an In-Line Dimmer switch. Some of these are being designed to be very small an compact, (as the part you linked to).

Comment: Yes, we're on the manufacturing side. The fixture can be modified but the ballast cannot.

Comment: Spec (very similar to this with changes): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfnap0NBgq_7RFDkLuk3lOMYWzto8z5T/view?usp=sharing